# How to iterate through an ICollection type property with reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection

The title covers a very tiny part of what I'm trying to achieve, so be informed ahead. I'm trying to build a generic way of properly updating collection properties of an entity when that entity itself is updated. In the nutshell I want to do something similar to the approach explained [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-one-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) but I want to go generic way. For that I have created an attribute called `EntityCollectionPropertyAttribute` and marked those properties of entities that 
I need to be updated too. Here's an example:

```
   public class Teacher{
      public int TeacherId{get;set;}
      public string Name{get;set;}
   }

   public class Student{
      public int StudentId{get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
      [EntityCollectionProperty]
      public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers{get;set;}
   }


 public bool IsPropertyAnEntityCollection(PropertyInfo prop){
     return Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(EntityCollectionPropertyAttribute));
 }

 public void Update<T>(T entity)where T:class{
    DbEntityEntry entry = MyDbContext.Entry(entity);
    foreach (var prop in entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if(IsPropertyAnEntityCollection(prop)){
            //Here's where I get stuck
        }
    }
 }
```

Lets say the parent entity that has been updated is a Student. Besides Name (and possibly ID) properties, I need the Teachers to be updated as well. So in the commented area I need something like this:

```
 var updatedTeachers=studentEntity.Teachers.ToList();
```

but of course generic way. I will also have to look inside the DbContext for the teachers DBSet independently. So I will need something like this too:

```
var exisitingTeachers=MyDbContext.Teachers.ToList();
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `ToList` method by passing property value `prop.GetValue(entity)` in this method:

```
private IList CollectionToList(object value)
{
    var collectionType = value.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.First();
    var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList");
    var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(collectionType);
    return (IList)genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { value });
}
```

In this way you will be able to iterate through collection. 
If type of property value `List` or `Array` and there is no need in creating new collection you can just cast value to `IList` and iterate through it.

For getting values from database context you can use `Set` method:

```
var dbset = MyDbContext.Set(prop.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First());
```

`dbset` also could be passed to `CollectionToList` method, but in that way you will load all table rows from table which could take a lot of time and memory.